# How to use tfs commands in nant script?

Tags: command-line, tfs, nant

I want to get latest a folder of TFS source control using TFS get command option in my nant script.
I have followed that link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx

```
 <property name="TF" value="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe&quot;" />
 <Exec Command="$(TF) C:\TFS-Build\Get-App>TF.exe get $/Main/XYZ /all /overwrite /force /recursive /noautoresolve /noprompt"></Exec>
```

where "C:\TFS-Build\Get-App" is the mapping location of that folder($/Main/XYZ) i want to download.
Can anyone please help me to run this command in nant script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<property name="TF" value="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe&quot;" />
 <Exec program="${TF}" workingdir="C:\TFS-Build\Get-App" commandline="get $/Main/XYZ /all /overwrite /force /recursive /noautoresolve /noprompt"></Exec>
```

Check this page for more details:[EXEC Task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/nightly/latest/help/tasks/exec.html)